# Tensorflow 2.0 can't use GPU, something wrong in cuDNN? :Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, nvidia, tensorflow2.x

I am trying to understand and debug my code. I try to predict with a CNN model developed under tf2.0/tf.keras on GPU, but get those error messages.
could someone help me to fix it?

here is my environmental configuration

```
enviroments:
python 3.6.8
tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0-rc0
nvidia 418.x
CUDA 10.0
cuDNN 7.6+**
```

and the log file,

```
2019-09-28 13:10:59.833892: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-09-28 13:11:00.228025: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-09-28 13:11:00.957534: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2019-09-28 13:11:00.963310: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2019-09-28 13:11:00.963416: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node mobilenetv2_1.00_192/Conv1/Conv2D}}]]
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_15_expand_BN/cond/then/_630/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0=====>GPU Available:  True
=====> 4 Physical GPUs, 1 Logical GPUs

mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_15_expand_BN/cond/then/_630/Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_15_depthwise_BN/cond/then/_644/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_15_depthwise_BN/cond/then/_644/Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_15_project_BN/cond/then/_658/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_15_project_BN/cond/then/_658/Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_16_expand_BN/cond/then/_672/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_16_expand_BN/cond/then/_672/Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_16_depthwise_BN/cond/then/_686/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_16_depthwise_BN/cond/then/_686/Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_16_project_BN/cond/then/_700/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/block_16_project_BN/cond/then/_700/Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/Conv_1_bn/cond/then/_714/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
mobilenetv2_1.00_192/Conv_1_bn/cond/then/_714/Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NSFW_Server.py", line 162, in <module>
    model.predict(initial_tensor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 915, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 722, in predict
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 393, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 3625, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1081, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1121, in _call_impl
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1224, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 511, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node mobilenetv2_1.00_192/Conv1/Conv2D (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_10727]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

The code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("=====>GPU Available: ", tf.test.is_gpu_available())
    tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

    gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    if gpus:
        try:
            # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs

            tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(gpus[0], 'GPU')
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
            logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
            print("=====>", len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
        except RuntimeError as e:
            # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
            print(e)

    paras_path = "./paras/{}".format(int(2011))
    model = tf.keras.experimental.load_from_saved_model(paras_path)
    initial_tensor = np.zeros((1, INPUT_SHAPE, INPUT_SHAPE, 3))
    model.predict(initial_tensor)
```

Answer (score 13):

You have to check that you have the right version of CUDA + CUDNN + TensorFlow (also ensure that you have all installed).

A couple of examples of running configurations are presented below(**UPDATE** FOR **LATEST** VERSIONS OF **TENSORFLOW**)

1. Cuda `11.3.1` + CuDNN `8.2.1.32` + TensorFlow `2.7.0`
2. Cuda `11.0` + CuDNN `8.0.4` + TensorFlow `2.4.0`
3. Cuda `10.1` + CuDNN `7.6.5` (normally > `7.6`) + TensorFlow `2.2.0`/TensorFlow `2.3.0` (TF >= `2.1` requires CUDA >=`10.1`)
4. Cuda `10.1` + CuDNN `7.6.5` (normally > `7.6`) + TensorFlow `2.1.0` (TF >= `2.1` requires CUDA >=
   `10.1`)
5. Cuda `10.0` + CuDNN `7.6.3`  + / TensorFlow `1.13`/`1.14` / TensorFlow `2.0`.
6. Cuda `9.0` + CuDNN `7.0.5` + TensorFlow `1.10`

Usually this error appears when you have an incompatible version of TensorFlow/CuDNN installed. In my case, this appeared when I tried using an older TensorFlow with a newer version of CuDNN.

**If for some reason you get an error message like(and nothing happens afterwards) :

> Relying on the driver to perform ptx compilation

Solution : Install the latest nvidia driver

[SEEMS TO BE SOLVED IN `TF >= 2.5.0`] (see below):

**Only for Windows Users** : Some late combintations of CUDA, CUDNN and TF may not work, due to a bug (a `.dll` extension named improperly). To handle that specific case, please consult this link: [Tensorflow GPU Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65608713/tensorflow-gpu-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cusolver64-10-dll-dlerror-cuso)

Comment: thank you, to make sure that CUDA/cuDNN/TF are right version, I pulled an image from docker hub which is "tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.0rc0-gpu-py3", and ran my code in container...But it still doesn't work and occurs same error massages.

Comment: Try to install them by hand on your own and then check again with the dependencies installed in the Docker image. There must be a slight difference that you are missing.

Comment: Thanks, Have anyone tried with any above versions ? like cuda 10.1 + CuDNN 7.64.

Comment: I have modified the answer to be clearer. Cuda 10.0 not only 10, because there is a difference between 10.0 and 10.1.

Comment: @Profstyle I have updated the answer for the latest TensorFlow

Comment: How about Tensorflow 2.2.0? Which Cuda and CuDNN version are compatible?

Comment: @jakes I have to check it out, for the moment on one of my PCs I have CUDA 10.0 + TF 1.14 and on my laptop CUDA 10.1 + TF 2.1 with the CUDNNs mentioned above. Unfortunately it won't be until the beginning of July when I try to see the other configuration.

Comment: @mobinalhassan you will need CUDA 10.1

Comment: @TimbusCalin I have install CUDA Version 10.2.89 how i'm able to downgrade this...i'm having the problem of memory out of run

Comment: You need to uninstall completely CUDA and then perform a clean installation of CUDA 10.1.

Comment: @VinSentTeZla did my answer solve your problem in the end?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing issues regarding the above error(For Windows platform), I sorted it just by installing CuDNN version compatible with the CUDA already installed in the system.

1. - This suitable version can be downloaded from the website [Download CuDNN from Developer's portal](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive). You might need Nvidia account for it. This will be easily created by providing mail id and filling a questionnaire.
2. - To check the CUDA version, run `NVCC --version`.
3. - Once the suitable version is downloaded, extract the folder from the zip file.
4. - Go to the bin folder of the extracted folder. copy the `cudnn64:7.dll` and paste it in the CUDA's bin folder. In my case, the location where Cuda is installed is `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\bin`.
5. - This would most probably solve the problem.

My system details:

1. Windows 10
2. CUDA 10.0
3. TensorFlow 2.0
4. GPU- Nvidia GTX 1060

I also found this blog [Installing TensorFlow with CUDA and GPU support on Windows 10.](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781) very useful.

Answer (score 0):

before cuda10.1 + cudnn8.0.5 ,by change cudnn7.6 solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Check the instructions on this TensorFlow GPU instruction [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#ubuntu_1604_cuda_90_for_tensorflow_1130) for your OS. It resolved issue for me on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and Tensorflow 2.0