# Colab: UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm when using TF 2.5

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, cudnn

I seem to be having problems when using tensorflow 2.5 on Google Colab. I assume there is some  incompatibility between the CUDA version and/or CuDNN version. How would I fix them?

I checked the [CUDA version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcewk.png) used by colab. It is 11.2 which should be ok with tf2.5. That would mean that the problem is with CuDNN, right?

Code to reproduce:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.5.0
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255.0
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255.0

def my_model():
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3)(inputs)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = keras.activations.relu(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = keras.activations.relu(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = keras.activations.relu(x)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(10)(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model


model = my_model()
model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-4),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=10, verbose=2)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=64, verbose=2)
```

[Error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX0ii.png)

I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873568/unknownerror-failed-to-get-convolution-algorithm) but I get the same error.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873568/unknownerror-failed-to-get-convolution-algorithm) also proposes I use `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)` but again - that does not work - I get the same error.

I am interested in using GPU. I know that everything works fine without hardware acceleration.

Comment: What's your cuDNN version?

Comment: How do I check the cuDNN on Google Colab?

Comment: Set that hardware accelerator to `None`. This will disable GPU in colab and your code will run fine.

Comment: Yes, but I want to run the code using a GPU. This code is only for reproducibility, but I need to use a GPU in the general case.

Comment: Google said, do not install any TensorFlow version by `!pip install` on their [website](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb#scrollTo=8UvRkm1JGUrk). So, if you want to use GPU, then use it with TensorFlow 2.6.

Comment: @AdarshWase Thank you for the information. I guess I would have to update my code. If you want post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it.

Comment: i have TF 2,7, !nvcc--ver says CUDA 11,1 and !!nvidia-smi says CUDA 11.2,  Isn;t this a disconnect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb#scrollTo=8UvRkm1JGUrk) documentation, Google warns us not to install/downgrade TensorFlow version using `!pip` command.
They wrote:

> Colab builds TensorFlow from source to ensure compatibility with our
> fleet of accelerators. Versions of TensorFlow fetched from PyPI by pip
> may suffer from performance problems or may not work at all.

Which means if we install any other TensorFlow, that version might not be compatible with their provided GPU/TPU configuration. So, just use TensorFlow 2.6 (which is the latest version) and it is so much similar to version 2.5.

Comment: ok.  good to know.  what happens if you get same error using the default tensorflow..