# Tensorflow GPU Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

When i run

```
import tensorflow as tf 
tf.test.is_gpu_available(
    cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None
)
```

I get the following error

[image]

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**Step 1**

```
 Move to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin
```

**Step 2**

```
Rename file cusolver64_11.dll  To  cusolver64_10.dll
```

[image]

```
 cusolver64_10.dll
```

[image]

Comment: Creating a symlink with powershell also works and is probably preferred:  

`New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path .\cusolver64_10.dll -Target .\cusolver64_11.dll`

Comment: @DouglasMarttinen Thanks it will help others

Comment: Why doesn't it work with cusolver64_11? I had this same issue even after updating my tensorflow...

Comment: Seems not too profesional answer but it works. Thank you :)

Comment: this will cause the problem in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698035/failed-to-get-convolution-algorithm-this-is-probably-because-cudnn-failed-to-in

Comment: Would it be more future proof to make a copy of the file, rename the copy and keep the original?

Comment: I got this error"Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found" and I copy the cusolver64_10.dll as cusolver64_11.dll to solve this problem. [My tensorflow-gpu version is 2.5, with cudnn64_8.dll]

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR For `TensorFlow` ver >= 2.4.0 on `Windows`, install exactly those versions of `CUDA Toolkit` and `cuDNN` highlighted below i.e. those listed in the official requirements.(v11.0 as opposed to v11.2)

---

On `Windows`, the `TensorFlow`^ install requirements at the time of writing are as stated [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)

1. NVIDIA® GPU drivers —CUDA® 11.0 requires 450.x or higher.
2. **CUDA® Toolkit** —TensorFlow supports CUDA® **11** (TensorFlow >= 2.4.0)
3. CUPTI ships with the CUDA® Toolkit.
4. **cuDNN SDK 8.0.4**.
5. (Optional) TensorRT 6.0 to improve latency and throughput for inference on some models.

The problem you are facing has probably to do with the version of CUDA® Toolkit. `Tensorflow` is picky about the version of dependencies. Have a look inside `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin`**. You should be able to find most^^ of the dlls needed by `TensorFlow` there. You may notice that it contains `cusolver64_11.dll` as opposed to the expected `cusolver64_10.dll` as stated in the output.

Though the renaming hack mentioned in an answer above works, it's not guaranteed to work reliably all the time. The simple and correct solution is to install the correct dependencies, to begin with.

At the time of writing the compatible versions of `CUDA Toolkit` and `cuDNN` are

```
CUDA Toolkit 11.0 (May 2020)
cuDNN v8.0.4 (September 28th, 2020), for CUDA 11.0
```

from among the plethora of available versions of both,  listed [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) & [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive).

More recent versions (I tested v11.0 onwards) aren't yet supported. I remember having the same problems with an earlier version of TensorFlow a few years back.

---

^   For ver >1.15, `TensorFlow` has GPU support included by default hence the CUDA requirements. When unavailable, `TensorFlow` works fine - it just reverts to CPU execution.
**  Or wherever you installed the toolkit
^^ `cudnn64_8.dll` comes with `cuDNN SDK`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It turns out that CUDA 11.0 contains cusolver64_10.dll (that's probably why they indicate CUDA v11.0 in the tensorflow build guide here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows). Make sure to download cudnn as well!

Answer (score 1):

For TensorFlow 2.4.1, the renaming hack will work if CUDA 11.2 needs to be installed.  I suggest installing CUDA 11.0 + cuDNN 8.0.4 for TF 2.4.1, as @lineage wrote above, and then the renaming won't be necessary, and your GPU will be recognized.

For TensorFlow 2.5.0, I just got my GPU recognized using CUDA 11.2.2 + cuDNN 8.1.1. In that case, DO NOT rename the cusolver file.  TF 2.5.0 expects the "cusolver64_11.dll" filename.

```
c> python
Python 3.9.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, May 10 2021, 22:10:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2021-05-28 08:11:24.517894: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
>>> print(tf.version.VERSION)
2.5.0
>>> print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')),
...       '\nDevice: ', tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
2021-05-28 08:12:19.501812: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-05-28 08:12:19.530869: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 with Max-Q Design computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.468GHz coreCount: 20 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.32GiB/s
2021-05-28 08:12:19.531377: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-05-28 08:12:19.597785: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-05-28 08:12:19.597992: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-05-28 08:12:19.618849: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-05-28 08:12:19.634321: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-05-28 08:12:19.677539: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library **cusolver64_11.dll**
2021-05-28 08:12:19.731541: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-05-28 08:12:19.746271: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-05-28 08:12:19.746674: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
Num GPUs Available:  1
Device:  [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
>>>
```

Comment: you can look at my comments in the first answer.

Comment: @Hong Cheng, yes, I had the same experience as you with TF 2.5.0.  I think that I had renamed the file to the "cusolver64_10.dll" name during previous attempts to get GPU support for TF 2.4.1.  Using CUDA Toolkit 11+,  use "cusolver64_10.dll" for TF 2.4.1, and keep the original file name, "cusolver64_11.dll," for TF 2.5.0.