# GPU card not picked up by tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0, nvidia

I installed the tensorflow-gpu version, and tried to test the GPU setup as suggested

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

However, I got the following information

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

My machine does have GPU card, shown as follows, why it is not picked by Tensorflow

[image]

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you do not have the right combination of the following:

1. CUDA
2. CuDNN
3. TensorFlow

Please check my answer here, for a correct combination of the aforementioned : [Tensorflow 2.0 can't use GPU, something wrong in cuDNN? :Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143637/tensorflow-2-0-cant-use-gpu-something-wrong-in-cudnn-failed-to-get-convoluti/58143787#58143787)